# GORM read only columns

Tags: grails, triggers, grails-orm, go-gorm

Most of our tables have one or more columns which are set by the database, either by a trigger, or we want to use the database default value (which requires not sending the field at all in the insert or update)

This includes transaction dates set in the dB (so all the times are times stamped very accurately by a single source, not relying on the accuracy of the time on an arbitrary server or pc.)

The second VERY common use case is say if a customer record has his address and a last logged in field.  the last logged in field (and number of failed logins) is set by another part of the system (e.g. by a web site server).  The current overly simplistic CRUD system which GORM provides would overwrite such a field when an operator or customer edits their address for example. This is because GORM includes in its update and insert statements every field, even if it's null, or if it has not been changed.

We need a way to scrub the field from inserts and updates, but still have it used in the read calls.
I.e. a true "read only" attribute.

We tried this:

```
    failedLogins editable: false, attributes: [readonly:true]
```

Which has no effect on the SQL generated (and doesn't even affect the scaffolded UIs - its still editable in create and edit, in grails 2.4.4 at least, but thats another story)

When we do want to explicitly write one of these fields, such as number of failed logins, we would resort to using embedded SQL.

I saw this post: [Read-Only columns](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Read-Only-columns-td1390025.html)

Which asks exactly the same question, but only gives one solution, which is this plugin:

[extended GORM mappings](http://grails.org/plugin/extended-gorm-mappings)

Unfortunately, this plugin has not been updated since 2010, and only works with 1.3.  We need something which works with 2.4.4.

Any grails app which has multiple systems which edits *independent* fields needs something like this, or to do extensive locking (Which is usually out of the question).

E.g. an operator opens the customer details for editing, edits something editable (e.g. address), then the operator fails a login on the website (a different grails or non-grails app), then the operator saves the player details.  If the saving included the numberOfFailedLogins field, the system would fail.  If opening the player details for editing locked the player, then the player would not be able to login, as updating the "lastLoggedIn" or "numFailedLogins" would fail to be able to write due to the lock.  The solution is VERY simple - read only columns.  Another way would be to put each read only type field in their own tables, but this would be untenable (and result in hundreds of one field tables)

Or we go back to using MyBatis, which has no such issues, and full control.  Sadly, there is no good mybatis plugin for grails.

Comment: Another good use case for read only columns is if you have a one-to-many which is a List on one side. In that case, adding an element by setting its belongsTo field doesn't seem right because it doesn't say anything about the order it will have in the List. It'd be nice to make the belongsTo side read-only, so you can only things like the addToX() method on the hasMany side. Unfortunately, overriding the belongsTo setter with a method that throws an exception breaks GORM itself.

Comment: Hi @SeyedHosseinHosseinimotlagh, I am approving your edit but I notice that you are fixing a spelling error in a code snippet (`failedLoggins` -> `failedLogins`). I know nothing about the involved technology, could you make sure this typo is not part of the OP’s problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [derived properties](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#derivedProperties) for string and number properties:

```
class Batch {
    String name
    Integer timesRun

    static mapping = {
        timesRun formula: 'times_run' //times_run is a column in the "batch" table
    }
}
```

In the code above, `timesRun` would be read in from the database but ignored in inserts and updates as Hibernate considers the column a calculated one.

*Updated the example because the original one may have been misleading*

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  Unfortunately, I do not beieve calculated columns address or solve the two use cases - we need to find a way to not put certain columns in the insert and update calls SQL, but to include them in the read calls.

Comment: So what's the difference between a trivially calculated column and a read-only column?

Comment: A read only column is one set in the database (e.g. via a trigger).  e.g. creationDate, or balance. They are calculated and written in the database itself for security and performance (think thousands of concurrent users, many components (not all grails) and of a system dealing with large amounts of cash).  a calculated column is something completely different.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood my example (copying a column was simplest for me to test but it may have mislead you): you can put columns unknown to Hibernate into `formula`, such as your `failedLogins` column which doesn't have to appear anywhere else in the domain class (it does have to exist in the DB though, obviously). It would be read in on selects but not affected by inserts or updates, as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't specifically answer your question, but you can use dynamicUpdates to tell GORM to only update the properties of the domain object that have changed during the current session. So as long as you don't change the "read-only" property in your code it won't be set in the SQL update statement generated by Grails. For added safety you could override (and noop) the setter so that your code can never change that property.

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/dynamicUpdate.html

One of the downsides of dynamicUpdates is that it might make the Hibernate query cache less useful. However, it seems that some Grails/Hibernate experts recommend that you disable the query cache anyway (at least in older versions of Grails). Not sure if that's true of Grails 2.4+

- http://grails.github.io/grails-howtos/en/performanceTuning.html
- http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2012/11/12/the-false-optimism-of-gorm-and-hibernate/
- http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/